# Generic Meyers Singleton implementation in C++

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++17, singleton

Is this a correct implementation of a generic Meyers Singleton in C++17? Any tips appreciated.

*Singleton.h*

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H

template<class T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    
    static T& get()
    {
        static T obj;
        return obj;
    }

protected:

    Singleton() = default;
    virtual ~Singleton() = default;
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton(Singleton&&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(Singleton&&) = delete;

};

#endif
```

*MySingleton.h*

```
#ifndef MYSINGLETON_H
#define MYSINGLETON_H

class MySingleton : public Singleton<MySingleton>
{
    friend class Singleton<MySingleton>;

public:

    // public members

private:
    
    MySingleton() {};
    ~MySingleton() {};

};

#endif
```

Comment: You will find issues with using templated singletons and shared libraries. You may have a single instance per shared library the compiler is under no obligation to remove duplicates across shared libraries (as the language does not even consider this).

Comment: Sinelton is best used in conjunction with a builder pattern. Otherwise, you will have issues with testing. You should be able to install a different Singleton object depending on the context of where you using it (Still keeping the same concept of having one object for the lifetime of the application it just may be different in different contexts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview

I am not sure this byes you anything in savings.
Its one static function and making sure that you can't copy/move the object.

There are some issues aound using templates to implement this as I have tried exactly the same before. If this is a single application it is find but if you start using shared libraries then you may run into issues where you have several instances of `T` because there is a unique version of `get()` in every shared library that has not been removed.

### Code Review

Not unique.

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H
```

Put your code in a namespace and add the namespace the include guards.

---

Reading ahead it looks like this only works because you assume `T` inherits from `Singleton` and thus makes sure that all the copy/move semantics are disabled.

```
    static T& get()
    {
        static T obj;
        return obj;
    }
```

But your `get()` method does not validate this. So I could call this method with anything and get a reference to a thing that is not a signelton.

```
    std::string myString = Singleton::get<std::string>();
```

You can make sure that the class works correctly by using `static_assert`.

```
    static T& get()
    {
        static_assert(std::derived_from<Singelton, T> == true);

        static T obj;
        return obj;
    }
```

---